# Помогите правильно установить значение функции

Tags: c#, autoit

Доброго времени помогите пожалуйста установить параметр flag = 1 по умолчанию равно 0 не знаю как это прописать в коде?

вот мой код:

```
var handle = AutoItX.WinGetHandle("NoxPlayer");
AutoItX.WinActivate(handle);
var button1 = AutoItX.ControlGetHandle(handle, "[CLASS:subWin; INSTANCE:1]");
AutoItX.ControlClick(handle, button1);
AutoItX.MouseClick("LEFT", 851, 517);
AutoItX.Send ("My contact here");
```

[image: параметр которой нужно установить]

Answer (score 4):

Если необязательный параметр не указывается в вызове, то используется его значение по умолчанию. Чтобы использовать какое-то свое, то нужно его указать вручную.

```
AutoItX.Send("My contact here", 1);
```

1 - значение необязательного параметра flag